# What is the GCP Service Account role to create Cloud Scheduler jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a service account that has the usual roles to deploy images to Cloud Run instances and all is working fine. This is done through a GitHub Actions workflows that setups `gcloud` using the provided `setup-gcloud` action.

I wrote a bash script that runs some gcloud commands to create some Scheduler's jobs required for my project.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

run_command() {
    gcloud scheduler jobs describe $1 --location=europe-west1 && echo "Job $1 already exists, skipping..." ||
        echo "Creating scheduler job $1 with schedule $2 and uri $3$4..." &&
        gcloud scheduler jobs create http $1 --location=europe-west1 \
            --schedule "$2" \
            --uri "$3$4" \
            --http-method $5 \
            --time-zone "Europe/Rome"
}
```

When running this in my workflow, the Action returns this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.scheduler.jobs.describe) PERMISSION_DENIED: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudscheduler.jobs.get" for the resource "projects/***/locations/europe-west1/jobs/***" (or the resource may not exist).
Creating scheduler job *** with schedule 30 * * * * and uri ***...
ERROR: (gcloud.scheduler.jobs.create.http) PERMISSION_DENIED: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudscheduler.jobs.create" for the resource "projects/***/locations/europe-west1" (or the resource may not exist).
```

The service account used to auth the gcloud instance inside the Action has the Cloud Scheduler Service Agent role assigned, which does not have the required permissions to do what I need.

The problem is that when trying to grant the Cloud Scheduler Admin role to this service account, it does not appear to be available in the list.

Do I have to create a custom role or am I doing something wrong with my service account usage?

Screenshot to show that the role doesn't appear in the list:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's quite odd that the role is not appearing the list, but you can make use of `gcloud` to attach the admin role to the service account:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  test-proj1@example.domain.com \
  --member='serviceAccount:test-proj1@example.domain.com' \
  --role='roles/cloudscheduler.admin'
```

EDIT:

It is possible that the Role may be somehow disabled, in order to enable it you can follow the next steps:

- Open the Google Cloud Console and navigate to the IAM & Admin page for your project.
- In the IAM & Admin page, click on the "Roles" tab.
- Search for the "Cloud Scheduler Admin" role using the search bar or by scrolling through the list of roles.
- Once you have found the "Cloud Scheduler Admin" role, click on the "Restore" button next to it.
- A confirmation window will appear. Click on the "Restore" button to confirm that you want to restore the role.
- Once you have confirmed, the role will be restored and you will be able to assign it to users or service accounts as needed.

Comment: Well, even with this command I can't add the role.
(gcloud.iam.service-accounts.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Role roles/cloudscheduler.admin is not supported for this resource.

What could it be that is blocking this service account to gain this role?

Comment: Are there any deny policies in place in your project/organisation? Because predefined roles are always available unless you've been removed from accessing some of them. As seen here in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-overview#deny-rules) you can deny someone from adding certain permissions, and it can be the case for you

Comment: I'm owner to the project

Comment: Have updated with steps on how to restore the job, can check if this is what happened?

Comment: Thank you, but the role has status 'Enabled' and there is no Restore button next to it

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. I created a cloud scheduler job some months ago in a different project no problem. Now on another project, the `cloudscheduler.admin`  role doesn't exist, only the service agent.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [document](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth) `Cloud Scheduler Service Agent` role is enough for a service account to schedule a job by using the cloud scheduler. In addition to this if you are using the cloud run to perform the job as per your requirement you need to provide **Cloud Run Service Agent** Role as well. In case if you are using cloud functions then you need to provide a **Cloud functions service agent** role.

In your invoke method try passing the service account email id by giving the  `--oidc-service-account-email` flag

```
$ gcloud scheduler jobs create http HELLO \
  --schedule="30 * * * *" --uri=$URI \
  --oidc-service-account-email=CLIENT_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
```

Refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth#gcloud) to know more about cloud scheduler with http authentication.

In case a normal scheduler wont work then try using the alpha and beta scheduler commands as well

1. [alpha
   scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/scheduler/jobs/create/http)
2. [beta
   scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/scheduler/jobs/create/http)

For more detailed information about cloud schedulers refer these documents [DOC1](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/http)
[DOC2](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/setup)

Comment: Have you got time to check this answer? Is it useful?